# How to change API Version in Azure Search .NET SDK

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I see the (probably) correct property, but I cannot set it since it's private...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.search.searchserviceclient.apiversion.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK targets the most recent, non-preview API version (today it's 2015-02-28). Features that are in preview can be used through Azure Search REST API. What are you trying to do?

Yesterday we released the [1.1.0 version](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search) of our SDK that includes support for Lucene query language. You can read about the roadmap for our SDK here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-search-sdk-roadmap/.

Comment: We started using Azure Search early in its development and currently rely on a customized version of [RedDog.Search](https://github.com/reddog-io/RedDog.Search). I remember that we needed to change the API-Version string at some point, to use features that would not have been available otherwise. At the moment we migrate our code to Search SDK and have no intention to change the API-Version string, but we may want to do that in the future. But that's no problem I guess... If we can't change the string, we'll just fork the Search SDK project for our internal use. Thx for your response!